# Given $x^2 +px + q$ has roots -1 & 4, find the values for p & q.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given $x^2 +px + q$ has roots $-1$ & $4$, find the values for $p$ & $q$.

Attempt:
$$
x = \frac{-p\pm\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}\\(p + 2x)^2 = p^2 - 4q\\
p^2 + 4px + 4x^2 = p^2 -4q
\\
q = -x^2 - px
\\
q = -(-1)^2 -p(-1)
\\
q = -1 - p
\\
q = -(4)^2-p(4)
\\
q = -16 - 4p
\\
-1 - p = - 16 - 4p
\\
3p = -15
\\
p = -5
\\
q = -1 - (-5)
\\
q = 4
$$

According to the book the answer should be $-3$ & $-4$

Comment: [Use Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Vieta%27s%20formulas%20are,are%20used%20specifically%20in%20algebra).

Comment: You have made a sign error. You should get $q=-1+p$ and $q=-16-4p$.

Comment: Also just to let you know I have never seen the technique (which is correct /valid) you have used (putting values of $x$ to get equations for $p, q$). The more standard way is vieta formulas given in comment by @Dave.

Comment: Also appreciate your efforts to use mathjax (there are probably some issues there), but still a very good start for a beginner. +1 Do visit the [mathjax tutorial especially written for beginners](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site).

Comment: I have fixed the mathjax to the bare minimum that it is rendered properly. As you learn more mathjax you may be able to edit this so that it looks much better.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh
Thanks for your effort, I appreciate. I doubt we were expected to solve it using Vieta’s Formula, since complex numbers haven’t  been covered yet and most of the page looks like French. It looks interesting so I’ll look into it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

From $x^2 + px + q = a(x+1)(x-4) = x^2 -3x -4$ and from comparison of the coefficients follows $a = 1$, $p = -3$ and $q = -4$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: $x^2+px+q=(x+1)(x-4)=x^2-3x-4$, and by comparison $p=-3$ and $q=-4$.

Comment: You actually need to justify why you can just assume the quadratic is a product of the two factors you wrote down, because it is not in general true!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of substituting the roots later, you could have substituted them right at the start:

$(-1)^2+p·(-1)+q = 0$.
$(4)^2+p·(4)+q = 0$.

And it is easy from there.

Comment: Glad someone pointed this out. Even I was a bit surprised of the detour taken by asker.

Answer (score 0):

The Vieta's formulas tells you that

$$p=-(r+s),\\q=rs$$ (where $r,s$ are the roots).

Comment: Glad somebody responded this way.

Comment: @user2661923: good to know. I mentioned Vieta so that the OP knows about him. (Then I wanted to show the cubic case but was stuck because of the naming of the variables :-)